# Node.js import results in ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, requirejs, jsimport

Here is how I built and installed node.js(version: 20.11):

```
./configure --prefix=/home/tester/node
make -j8
make install
```

Here is how I set the environment:

```
export PATH=/home/tester/node/bin:$PATH
export NODE_PATH=/home/tester/node/lib/node_modules
```

Here is how I installed the module to be imported:

```
npm install -g express
```

The content of /tmp/test/package.json:

```
{
    "description": "Test me",
    "type": "module"
}
```

The content of /tmp/test/test.js:

```
import express from 'express'
```

Here is how I executed test.js:

```
node /tmp/test/test.js
```

Here is what happened when I executed test.js:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from /tmp/test/test.js
Did you mean to import express/index.js?
```

If I simply remove the line `"type": "module"` in package.json, and change `import express from 'express'` to `const express = require('express')`, then it works. So what is the problem for just using `import`? I am new to Node.js, and don't know how to figure the issue out. Someone please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this work? `import * as express from "express";`

Comment: @Charlie
Finally I figured the issue out: NODE_PATH simply doesn't work for import specifiers: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#no-node_path. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the way `import` works, this is an intentional action from the NodeJS team. There is a history behind it but it stems from a decision made long ago that ESM imports would work to automatically resolve index files and extensions (much like `require`) during the early days of TypeScript.

When using NodeJS ESM imports (not TypeScript ESM imports) you have to specify the file name as well as the extension.

As for `express` specifically, they don't specify any of the information in their package JSON to help support ESM imports as well as not planning to refactor their codebase from CommonJS to ESM.

- https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4933

When using the `import` style NodeJS, you'll end up having to do something similar to:

```js
import express from 'express/index.js'

// or the below depending on how they export their code
// import * as express from 'express/index.js'
```

---

If you care enough to dig into some conversation about NodeJS and `import`, this was recently brought up [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46006)

Comment: Finally I figured the issue out: NODE_PATH simply doesn't work for import specifiers: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#no-node_path. Thanks anyway. BTW: express now supports import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured the issue out myself: NODE_PATH simply doesn't work for import specifiers: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#no-node_path.